# Python class instances, index out of range

Tags: python, excel, class

Currently I am working in Python 3.8.0. I want to read from a excel file and make a list of instances.
Unfortunately it doesn't work, and I can't understand why.
At first I have written the code below:

```
    for rule in file:
    rule = rule.rstrip().split()
    print(rule)
    superheld = Superheld(*rule)
    superheld_lijst.append(superheld)
    print(superheld_lijst)
file.close()
```

But then I've got the error message that **init** is missing 7 required positional arguments, and I couldn't figure out why it doesn't work. Because *rule means that each element is given as a unique/different element.
After a while I've tried this:

```
    for rule in file:
    rule = rule.rstrip().split()
    print(rule)
    superheld = Superheld(rule[0], rule[1], rule[2], rule[3],
                          rule[4], rule[5], rule[6], rule[7])
    superheld_lijst.append(superheld)
    print(superheld_lijst)
file.close()
```

I thought this could work, but then I've got the error message that 'list index out of range'.
What have I to do to get a list of instances?

Comment: `Superheld(*rule)` is fine, *if* you verify before the call that `len(rule) == 7`. (And, I feel it is worth stating explicitly, that the elements in `rule` are in the order that `Superheld` expects.)

Comment: I really just want to use *rule, because I really don't like rule[0], rule[1] etc
Should I state in the for loop len(rule) ==7?
Like for len(rule)==7 in file:

Comment: `Superheld.__init__` expects 7 arguments. If `len(rule) != 7`, then `Superheld(*rule)` will either provide too many or too few arguments.

Comment: Does the output of `print(rule)` *look* like it has enough arguments for `Superheld`?

Comment: Alright, I am going to try that and let you know if it works
And yes below is a part of the output of print(rule)
['Number,Name,Type,HP,Superpower,SuperpowerStrength,SuperpowerAccuracy,FatigueFactor']
['1,Superman,Alien,1200,Storm', 'Breath,100,0.8,0.95']
['2,Hulk,Human,2000,Smash,300,0.3,0.92']
['3,Wolverine,Mutant,900,Adamantium', 'Claws,150,0.8,0.95']

Comment: Unfortunately len(rule) == 7 doesn't work, because he give an empty list.

Comment: You need to use `split(',')`, not `split()`, because you have what appears to be a CSV file.

Comment: Thanks, I've gotten a list with objects. I think I can move on
[<Superheld.Superheld object at 0x02B4F0E8>